# Perl Shell Wrapper for piping scripts and commands

Tags: perl, shell, command, bioinformatics, pipeline

I'm working on a bioinformatics project that involves piping together different scripts and input parameters for the analysis of Next-Gen Sequencing Illumina data. I need help with the wrapper script. Recall that a *wrapper* is a shell script that embeds a system command or utility, that accepts and passes a set of parameters to that command. Wrapping a script around a complex command-line simplifies invoking it.

Here's a minimal representation of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $barcode_file= shift;
unless($barcode_file){
    die "missing barcode file location, aborting.\n";
}

my $raw_data_location = '/data/local/samples/';
my $components_location= '~/read_cleanup/';
my $tmp_dir= '/tmp/';

open (FILEIN, $barcode_file) or die "couldn't open $barcode_file for read: $!\n";

while(<FILEIN>){
# input file format (tab delimited):
# Sample_Name    barcode    enzyme    size    paired    seq_file

    /^$/ and next; chomp;

    my ($sample, $barcode, $enzyme, $size, $pe, $seq_file)= split;

    $raw_file_data = "${raw_data_location}$seq_file"; #/data/local/samples/301.fq for instance

    # final output file
    my $final_output_file = "${tmp_dir}${sample}_reconciled_ends.fq"; # /tmp/D1_reconciled_ends.fq for instance

    # if the sample is paired ( 1 - paired, 0 - unpaired)
    if ($pe) {
        my $pipe_cmd= "${components_location}script01.pl $raw_data_file $barcode | ${components_location}script02.pl $enzyme | ${components_location}script03.pl  $size > $final_output_file";
    }
    system($pipe_cmd);

# at this point, $final_output_file should be saved in the
# tmp folder and contain the paired fastq data output

}
close (FILEIN);
```

Basically the wrapper reads the barcode.txt file and loops through each line (sample name) of the file. For each sample name, it generates the input parameters for each script in the the piped run. If the sample is paired data, then we do a piped run. The piping scheme goes like this:

```
# the input parameters are "fed" into the script and the output is piped
# as STDIN to the next script.
script01.pl [input parameters] | script02.pl [input parameters] | script03.pl [input parameters] > file.txt
```

`system($piped_cmd)` executes the piped run in the terminal.

Here's where I'm getting trouble, when I try to run the wrapper script from the terminal:

`./wrapper_example.pl barcode.txt`

It returns the following error message:

`sh: 1: /home/user/read_cleanup/script01.pl: not found`

Does anyone know what's wrong or how to fix this? thanks. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: **1.** In the  `if ($pe)` - are you sure you want to declare a  `my` variable here? **2.** Have you tried running `perl script01.pl | ...` etc? Does invoking the toolchain manually work? Try printing out the commands before they are invoked; do they differ?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the scripts for a piped run in the terminal: `./ script01 [input parameters] | script02.pl [input parameters] | script03.pl [input parameters] > tmp.txt` The tmp.txt stores the expected results. The variable `$pe` is either `1` if the data is paired or `0` if the data isn't paired.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying regarding the `my` variable in the `if ($pe)` statement. I declared the variable outside the if statement but that didn't help.

Comment: What happens when you run `ls -l /home/user/read_cleanup/script01.pl` ?

Comment: when I run that command, using the actual filename and directory, it returns `ls: cannot access /home/sam/read_cleanup/script01.pl: No such file or directory`

Comment: correction, the command returns: `-rwxr--r-- 1 sam sam 4272 Jul 14 21:04 /home/sam/read_cleaning/script01.pl` I don't know what I did differently before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `system()` syntax is `system("$command","$args1","$args2")` OR `system(@command)` where `@command=("$command","$arg1","$arg2")`. I would rather use back ticks to run the whole chain of commands like-

```
if ($pe) {
    `perl ${components_location}script01.pl $raw_data_file $barcode | perl ${components_location}script02.pl $enzyme | perl ${components_location}script03.pl  $size > $final_output_file`;
}
```

Comment: I missed something in my answer (see above code again). I would assume running perl would require invoking the `/user/bin/perl` (if its in that path) i.e. usually, you would run a perl script like `perl per_script.pl`. Since the backticks or `system()` function expects a command, which in this case should be `perl`.

Comment: ah okay, I think that was it. It's not giving me that error anymore. you explained it pretty well. It seems now I just have to make the changes throughout the script. it will take a sec but I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, /home/user/read_cleanup/script01.pl is not an executable, OR its shebang (first line starting with `#!`) points to the wrong Perl. It's kind of difficult to troubleshoot further without a bit more details.

Comment: As a side note, please do NOT use "`~`" in your paths within Perl. Perl does not understand/expand `~` - only shell does. In your specific case it worked because pipes and redirect forced `system()` call to use shell, but in general if the shell is not called it would result in the system call failing. use `$ENV{HOME}` instead of `~`

Comment: I agree, I think the problem is that `/home/user/read_cleanup/script01.pl` is not an executable. I must be running the command wrong. I removed the `~` and added the `$ENV{HOME}`. Now `./wrapper_example.pl barcode.txt` returns the error message: `sh: 1: {HOME}/read_cleanup/script01.pl: not found`

Comment: @cooldood3490 - do `chmod a+x /home/user/read_cleanup/script01.pl`